# GCC warns without cast, while MSVC warns with cast, why?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, warnings

I have a C library that allows user to `#define` a integer type and generate a function specialized for that integer type, much like C++ template function.

```
#define THE_INTTYPE  signed short
```

The function needs to know the minimum value that can be represent by `THE_INTTYPE`. For user's convenience, I do not require them to `#define` it. Instead, I set the most significant bit to get it.

```
typedef THE_INTTYPE rInt;
enum { /* assume */ char_bit = 8 };
rInt const rMin = ((rInt)1 << (sizeof(rInt) * char_bit - 1));
```

At this point, MSVC2017 at warning level 4 gives no warning, but `gcc -pedantic -Wall` gives `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]`. I understand why it complains though. It's because I've stepped over the MSB of signed integer.

> Whoa, the integer value implicitly converted from positive (before shift) to negative (after shift)! Seems like a mistake, better warns him. - GCC thought

I assert my intention by adding `(rInt)` cast so it becomes `(rInt)((rInt)1 <<...`. GCC no longer complains. MSVC2017, however, surprisingly gives a warning now: `warning C4310: cast truncates constant value`.

At last, I managed to "fix" it by casting the `1` to `uintmax_t`.

```
/* Perfect no warning code */
rInt const rMin = (rInt)((uintmax_t)1 << (sizeof(rInt) * char_bit - 1));
```

The question is, why? If MSVC2017 is stricter than GCC, why does it give warning if and only if I added the cast? **Why did MSVC2017 decide to give warning only after I added the cast?** Did I miss anything here?

```
((signed short)1) -> 0000 0000 0000 0001
<< (2 * 8 - 1) -> 1000 0000 0000 0000 // GCC warns, understandable, MSVC no warn
(signed short)((signed short)1 ... // GCC no warn, MSVC warns, why?
```

Answer (score 1):

So I went to read the official documentation of [C4310 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4310?view=vs-2017) once again, and found the keyword: **cast** and **truncate**.

Apparently MSVC thinks the **intentional casting** is **unintentional truncating**. How so? Let's see the official example.

```
long int a;
a = (char) 128;   // C4310, use value 0-127 to resolve
```

For MSVC, `char` is signed by default. Since a `signed char` ranges from -128 to 127, when the compiler saw someone trying to cast `128` as `char` which will surely end up as totally different value `-128`, the compiler will emit the warning C4310, because the casting seems like a mistake.

However, if you remove the cast, and directly assign the value to a `char` instead:

```
char c = 128; // warning?
```

You may think that, since MSVC smartly warns programmer about questionable casting, for sure it will emit a bigger warning on this one. Unfortunately, it would not. I repeat, **it would not emit any warning**.

So if you make a mistake, initialize `signed` variable with positive integer value that can only be represent by `unsigned`, MSVC will not warn you. MSVC will warn you only if you initialize with a value that even the `unsigned` version of the data type cannot handle.

```
char c = 255; // no warning
char c = 256; // warning: truncation from 'int' to 'char'
```

Or if you really want MSVC to check that for you, you need to cast.

```
char c = (char)128; // MSVC emits C4310
```

As such, I find C4310 unhelpful and possibly harmful. It seems to encourage C programmer not to cast things that should be cast. Because if you cast, it warns. If you no cast, it will not warn. So why cast when you can get away without casting? This is ridiculous IMHO.

In GCC, the situation reverses. Cast? No warning. No cast? Emit warning. It is just that simple.

As such, if you are trying to writing similar code that compiles without warning under both compiler, you are in a checkmate situation, as this question's title states, **GCC warns without cast, while MSVC warns with cast**. Welcome to the compiler-incompatible-with-each-other territory.

---

**Bouns**

Find minimum value that can be hold by an arbitrary signed integer type without warning from both compiler, without `uintmax_t`.

```
typedef short rInt;
rInt const rIntMin = (rInt)-1 << (sizeof(rInt) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

How it works? Take 16-bit short for example, the code turns `1111 1111 1111 1111` to `1000 0000 0000 0000`. Since the integral value is negative before bit-shift, and also negative after bit-shift, the operation is deemed safe, thus no warning from both compiler.